# How to fill background on dt/dd list to 100% width?

Tags: css

My goal is to create a list for mobile devices where the colors are altering.

If I use percentages for the width, then I can fill the altering row to 100%, but if I use px then the gray lines will not be filled until the lines end:

[image]

As this is the mobile version, I want to have the width of dt set to a maxiumum of the longest word +5px and the rest of the line (dd) space used for the description as this is the dynamic part of the line.

My code looks like this:

```
dl {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
dt {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
dd {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
.attributelist-striped .attributelist--key:nth-of-type(odd), .attributelist-striped .attributelist--value:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.attributelist-striped .attributelist--key, .attributelist-striped .attributelist--value {
    padding: 5px;
}

<section class="l-container" itemprop="offerDetails" itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer">
    <meta itemprop="price" content="6.390">
    <meta itemprop="currency" content="&euro;">
    <dl class="attributelist-striped">
        <dt class="attributelist--key">Matterial Armband:</dt>
        <dd class="attributelist--value">Gold/Stahl</dd>

        <dt class="attributelist--key">Matterial Gehäuse:</dt>
        <dd class="attributelist--value">Gelbgold mit Stahl</dd>
     </dl>
</section>
```

How can this be altered in order to have 100% gray lines and the dt line set to max length of the text + 5px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get the `dd` elements to fill the rest of the line, by calculating the necessary width:

```
dd {
  width: calc(100% - 170px);
}
```

You would need to go with 170px here, because both dd and dt have a 5px padding. If you add `box-sizing: border-box`, you can go with the more “logical” value of 150px here, that matches the width specified for the `dt` elements.